# Put the result of one specific row of a JOIN statement into a record variable in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Assume the 3 below tables:

```
student(sid NUMBER, sname VARCHAR2(100), gpa NUMBER)  
register(sid NUMBER, cid NUMBER, grade NUMBER)  
course(cid NUMBER, cname VARCHAR2(30), unit NUMBER)
```

I want to put the result of one specific row of a JOIN statement into a record variable, so I wrote the below code for this purpose:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE my_record IS RECORD (col1 student%ROWTYPE,
                              col2 register%ROWTYPE,
                              col3 course%ROWTYPE);
    lv_rec my_record;
BEGIN
    SELECT s.*, r.*, c.*  INTO lv_rec
    FROM student s, register r, course c
    WHERE s.sid = r.sid AND r.cid = c.cid AND s.sid = &id1 AND c.cid = &id2 ;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OK, DONE!');
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR: ' || SQLCODE || ' : ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

but I get the following error in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
Error report -  
ORA-06550: line 7, column 32:  
PLS-00597: expression 'LV_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type  
ORA-06550: line 7, column 32:  
PLS-00597: expression 'LV_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type  
ORA-06550: line 7, column 32:  
PLS-00597: expression 'LV_REC' in the INTO list is of wrong type  
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:  
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier  
ORA-06550: line 7, column 5:  
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored  
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"  
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.  
*Action:
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you really intending to put the entire student row into a single field in your record? How are you planning to use the record once it's populated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want each queried table's column values in one field per table, you can't use `select *`. The closest attempt I can imagine is:

```
    SELECT s.*, r.*, c.*  INTO lv_rec.col1, lv_rec.col2, lv_rec.col3
    FROM student s, register r, course c
    WHERE s.sid = r.sid AND r.cid = c.cid AND s.sid = &id1 AND c.cid = &id2 ;
```

But that gets `PLS-00494: coercion into multiple record targets not supported`.

So you need to specify which column go in which field and sub-field:

```
    SELECT s.sid, s.sname, s.gpa, r.sid, r.cid, r.grade, c.cid, c.cname, c.unit
    INTO lv_rec.col1.sid, lv_rec.col1.sname, lv_rec.col1.gpa,
      lv_rec.col2.sid, lv_rec.col2.cid, lv_rec.col2.grade,
      lv_rec.col3.cid, lv_rec.col3.cname, lv_rec.col3.unit
    FROM student s, register r, course c
    WHERE s.sid = r.sid AND r.cid = c.cid AND s.sid = &id1 AND c.cid = &id2 ;
```

... which works, but arguably makes it less useful to use `%rowtype` I suppose. You could also use schema-level object types rather than record types, but you can't define an object using `%rowtype`, and you'd still need to specify all the columns in the query explicitly to create the object instances.

It's probably just as simple to define your record type with all the columns from each table rather than using three rowtype fields, and that would allow you to eliminate the duplication of the join columns, `sid` and `cid` - or leave them out completely as you're filtering from them. And this way you can refer to `lv_rec.sname` rather than `lv_rec.col1.sname` - you don't have to know/care which rowtype field, and therefore which table, each value comes from.

One other option with one field per column is to use a cursor and declare your record type from that (as @MarkWagoner suggested):

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cur IS
      SELECT *
      FROM student s
      JOIN register r USING (sid)
      JOIN course c USING (cid)
      WHERE sid = &id1 AND cid = &id2 ;

    lv_rec cur%rowtype;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur INTO lv_rec;
    CLOSE cur;
...
```

The explicit joins with the `USING` syntax eliminate the duplicate columns from the select list, meaning you can still use `*`. Not sure how much of a help that really is though since you need to know the column/field names to be able to refer to them in the record anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your select statement in a cursor and then define the record as the cursor %ROWTYPE